# How to access a constraint by its label in matter-js?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I am currently building a game with react native game engine and matter-js. I want to be able to access the constraint by its label. I currently created it:

```js
let constraint = Constraint.create({
  label: "Rope",
  pointA: { x: 200, y: 0 },
  bodyB: initialBall,
});
```

The documentation provides examples on how to give a constraint a label but not how to access it.

Comment: What do you mean by "access it"? Using a string `"Rope"`...? Is there a problem with a custom data structure, e.g. `constraintsByLabel = {Rope: constraint}`?

Comment: @ggorlen yes, why should it be stored in a second data structure if it is already being stored in the world's bodies array

Comment: Are you looking for [`Composite.allBodies()`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Composite.html#method_allBodies)/Composites/Constraints? You'll still need to filter by label, which is probably a less desirable solution than using your own data structure. MJS is just a physics engine that lets you manage state as best fits your app. `World` is deprecated and shouldn't be used, BTW. This question was reposted in virtually identical form as [How do you access a body by it's label in MatterJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72092182/how-do-you-access-a-body-by-its-label-in-matterjs)