# How do you access a body by its label in MatterJS?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70477975/how-to-access-a-constraint-by-its-label-in-matter-js) but no answer was given.

To clarify the question, once a body is created, it is stored in the World/Composite.

The question is, given a body created like so:

```
Bodies.rectangle(0, 1000, 0, 100, {
                isStatic: true,
                label: "floor",
                friction: 0,
                render: {
                    fillStyle: 'light blue'
            },
})
```

How do you access the body using the label? (Assuming the body is added to the world)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no, there is no built in function that allows you to retrieve a body by its label. The reason is because labels aren't unique and retrieving a body by label can take really long. Imagine if there were thousands of bodies...

In any case, if you still want to retrieve a body by its label you can do this to search for the body in linear time:

```
// retrieve all bodies in the world and filter on label
// returns an array containing all bodies that have that label
function getBodiesByLabel(label, world) {
  return Composite.allBodies(world).filter(body => body.label === label)
}

const floorBodies = getBodiesByLabel('floor')

floorBodies.forEach(floorBody => console.log(floorBody))
```

If you only have a couple of bodies to look through, it's not that bad.

Source: [MatterJS GitHub Question](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/1124#issuecomment-1117268169)
Credit: [grantjenkins](https://github.com/grantjenkins) on GitHub

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by gfdb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72113377/6243352) works, but it involves a linear search over all bodies for each label lookup, O(n). As I mentioned in a [couple](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/1124#issuecomment-1117644469) of [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70477975/how-to-access-a-constraint-by-its-label-in-matter-js?noredirect=1#comment127381754_70477975), MJS does offer a `label` property for convenience, but doesn't purport to be a holistic entity management solution; it's just a physics engine library. There doesn't seem to be any backing data structure for labels, and that's probably a good thing. Leaning heavily on this single property seems to be an antipattern, expecting MJS to handle entity management when it's not intended to.

So, the general approach when using MJS standalone is to roll your own application-specific entity management solution that meets your needs, or use an opinionated framework like Phaser that offers an off-the-shelf solution.

A couple of common approaches are:

1. Use a *composition* pattern: write your own classes and keep fields for MJS bodies as implementation details (probably OK to be tightly-coupled for most use cases), along with whatever other data you need for your app. Group in data structures as needed and optionally inherit from your base classes as in normal OOP.

   ```js
   class Enemy {
     constructor(x, y, width, height, opts) {
       this.body = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(x, y, width, height, opts);
       this.kills = 0;
       this.cooldown = 30;
       // ... other important data that isn't necessarily MJS-related
     }

     update() {...}
     draw() {...}
     ...
   }

   const entities = {
     enemies: [new Enemy(...), ...],
     walls: [...],
     ...
   };
   ```
2. Use the bodies directly, but put them into an object of arrays organized by label:

   ```js
   const bodiesByType = {
     walls: [Matter.Bodies.rectangle(), ...],
     enemies: [Matter.Bodies.rectangle(), ...],
     players: [Matter.Bodies.rectangle(), ...],
     ...
   };
   ```

   ... or even skip the object and look them up by loose variable names `player`, `walls`, etc.
3. Use gfdb's approach for simple use cases where the above options might be premature optimization (although I don't think option 2 is much work).

Comment: Thanks for providing a way to get around it, but I find it odd that you would go as far as to comment on the original question asked by @bonvee99, comment on my copy of the question telling me to upvote the other one instead of asking a new one, comment on the issue on github, and then come answer the question ONLY AFTER I posted an answer. All without upvoting either my question or @bonvee99s? I don't understand but in any case, thank you for the answer, I hope it helps someone.

Comment: I watch the MJS tag and respond to issues I find interesting or well-asked, both on GH and here. The old question doesn't have an answer, and if you have the same question and find it useful, the normal approach isn't to re-ask the question. But now that that's happened and the new question has been answered (it's a slightly better, more general question), I decided that this would be the canonical thread between the two and hopefully we can close that one as a dupe, once this question gets an upvote or answer.

Comment: I'm happy to upvote this question, it's well-asked and the premise is reasonable. The hesitancy, however, is as I commented on the other SO thread and GH issue is that it smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). Neither question offers context for what the app is or what behavior label searching is supposed to implement. My goal with this answer is to steer people away from the idea that labels are useful for identifying entities or that MJS has a prescribed entity mangement system at all.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for responding. Most people in this tag (and SO in general) never respond to requests for clarification, as occurred in the other thread, which is why I never answered that one. Also, for awhile I was genuinely unsure of whether there wasn't a built-in way to search by label, but your research in the GH thread and combing the docs a bit gave me the assurance that there wasn't.

Comment: I strongly agree that it is an XY problem, good eye. It was for that reason that I ended up reworking my code to avoid needing to search for bodies all together. Very cool of you to watch this tag since there aren't many questions on SO about this package and since the docs aren't the best. You're welcome and thank you too.